# Is it proper to use "Connect With Us" in this case?

Tags: website-design, social-media, social-interfaces, contact-us

Our company is going to design the "Contact Us" area on our website like this:  http://take.ms/W973h3

If a visitor of our site clicks on any icon of the three apps Messenger, Whatsapp or Skype, they will go to the login webpage of the app and start a conversation with a customer client of our company. In this case, it is correct to use the title "Connect With Us" here? If not, what title should I use here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I like the "connect with us" better than "contact us", it feels more personal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best approach would be to see the title of the section from the users perspective. For example, instead of "follow us" to "Get quality content" or "Get... (whatever good you share on social media e.g. user stories, information, analytics etc - not sure what your product is)".

I would prefer "Talk to us" or "Chat with us" instead of "Connect with us". Depending on your product or your user reasons to contact you this might be more specific, for example: "Tell us what you like in our product", "Do you have an issue using our services", etc.

When it comes to choosing similar things like "Talk" VS "Chat" I would check the product and how you want it to be perceived and google trends, so you know what is used more and as so perceived more natural.

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=talk%20to%20us,connect%20with%20us,chat%20with%20us

Answer (score 0):

what are your visitors goals in that case that makes him use this option?
Is the visitors goal to "connect" with you because hes a potential business partner and/or someone who wants to get in touch with you or is the visitors goal to contact you in a potentially faster, more easy and personal way instead of using the contact form?

If the second goal is the case then something like "Ask us via.." could meet the expectations of the visitor better.

By the way i feel like "Connect with us" could fit better on the second part instead of "Follow us", since "Follow us" has kind of negative taste to it while "Connect with us" makes it more personal and engaging.